# How to shift back the offset of a topic within a stable Kafka consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I try to shift back the offset of topic within consumer group using following command:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server loclahost:9092 --group xxx-0 --topic schedule-changed --reset-offsets --shift-by -2 --execute
```

(Yes, I'm using kafka version > 1.x) As a result I got a message:

> Error: Assignments can only be reset if the group 'xxx-0' is
>   inactive, but the current state is Stable.

How can I change the state of group from **'stable'** to **'inactive'**?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `reset-offsets` option for kafka-consumer-groups.sh first checks to see if a consumer is active in that group before attempting to shift back your offsets. 'Stable' means you have an active consumer running.

Use the `describe-groups` option to check on your consumer groups:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $SERVERS --group $GROUP --describe
```

If you see an entry under 'CONSUMER-ID/HOST/CLIENT-ID' for your topic, that means you still have a consumer running. Once you shut down the app that's keeping the consumer alive your consumer group will be inactive and you'll be able to shift your offsets at will.

Comment: The original question is, how can we reset the offset while consumer group is stable? The answer you posted is something else. Could you please answer the exact question?

Comment: The answer is you can't.

Comment: Maybe it's related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9752

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but in contrast to kellanburket's answer there was no consumer running any more. In that case, I had to delete the consumer group:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper a.zookeeper.host:2181 --group the-group-name --delete
```

In newer versions of kafka, you may need to use:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server $SERVERS --group the-group-name --delete
```